# Why does COALESCE prevent the use of an index on a varchar, but not on a text column?

Tags: postgresql, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, index-tuning, varchar

Imagine a view which contains a `COALESCE` of two `varchar` columns from two different tables.

The underlying `varchars` are indexed in both tables.

In Postgres 11.6, filtering this view on the result of the `COALESCE` doesn't use the indexes, instead doing a table scan.

But if I change the columns to `text`, the very same view filtered on the same column, the index is used as you'd expect.

### Example

Suppose I have a table of measured values for some identifiers over time. There's also an almost identical table containing estimated values:

```sql
CREATE TABLE measured (
  id int,
  ts timestamp,
  identifier character varying,
  measured_value int
);
CREATE INDEX ON measured(identifier);

CREATE TABLE estimated (
  id int,
  ts timestamp,
  identifier character varying,
  estimated_value int
);
CREATE INDEX ON estimated(identifier);
```

Each table has 1 million rows of data in:

```sql
INSERT INTO measured
SELECT
    generate_series(1, 1000000),
    to_timestamp((random() * 100000)::int),
    left(md5(random()::text), 2),
    random() * 10;

INSERT INTO estimated
SELECT
    generate_series(1, 1000000),
    to_timestamp((random() * 100000)::int),
    left(md5(random()::text), 2),
    random() * 10;
```

Filtering on the `identifier` column in either table alone uses the index as we'd expect.

We have a view which returns all the measured data, and all the estimated data, combining into a single row where the identifier and timestamp are the same:

```sql
CREATE VIEW combined AS
SELECT
    COALESCE(measured.ts, estimated.ts) AS ts,
    COALESCE(measured.identifier, estimated.identifier) AS identifier,
    measured_value,
    estimated_value
FROM measured
FULL OUTER JOIN estimated ON measured.identifier = estimated.identifier
                         AND measured.ts = estimated.ts;
```

This combined view performs a table scan when filtered on the `identifier` column:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT * FROM combined
WHERE identifier = 'ab';
```

But if we change the data type of `identifier` to `text`, filtering the view uses the index as expected.

Is this a bug?

*For convenience, I've pasted the whole script [here](https://pastebin.com/n99Yz6Pa)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm the problem. Even in Postgres 13. Even after:

```
SET enable_seqscan = off;
```

... which forces the index if at all possible. To be precise, indexes *are* used, but as full index scans - a measure of last resort to avoid sequential scans. The telltale whether indexes are used meaningfully is an index condition instead of a filter in the `EXPLAIN` output. Like:

```
Index Cond: (identifier = 'ab'::text)
```

Instead of:

```
Filter: ((COALESCE(measured.identifier, estimated.identifier))::text = 'ab'::text)
```

The index scan alone, without index condition, "uses" the index but not in a useful manner:

```
->  Index Scan using measured_identifier_idx on measured
```

#### Simpler query

For starters, let's simplify the base query with the `USING` clause in the join condition:

```
CREATE VIEW combined AS
SELECT ts
     , identifier
     , m.measured_value
     , e.estimated_value
FROM   measured m
FULL   JOIN estimated e USING (identifier, ts);
```

Equivalent, except that the join columns `identifier` and `ts` are only added once to the list of output columns, which can only be beneficial, especially since `SELECT *` now delivers unique column names.

But it does nothing for the index issue.

#### Research

It certainly has to do with the fact that [`text` is "preferred" among string types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/catalog-pg-type.html#CATALOG-TYPCATEGORY-TABLE). `varchar` is binary compatible with `text`, basically just an alias, or rather, `varchar` is something like a domain with base type `text`. Indexes on `varchar` columns use the type `text` internally.

This makes Postgres add a cast to `text` when using the index (which is a no-op, really). Becomes evident in the `EXPLAIN` output, even for the simplest query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM combined WHERE identifier = 'ab';

...
Index Cond: ((identifier)::text = 'ab'::text)
...
```

This no-op of casting to `text` becomes an obstacle along the way. Not sure where the query planner loses confidence that the index is applicable anyway. Using `text` from the get-go obviously removes the problem.

[Views are implemented with a query rewrite rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-views.html). I think we can rule out any involvement of the rule system. I can reproduce the problem with the  query alone, without `VIEW` (in Postgres 13):

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2b8da87160ed33b043d4558d1cdd233e)*

Again, indexes are used with data type `text`:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f0648040ceaa2bad7ca20e202bdacf10)*

But only with `COALESCE` and `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

To make sure, I tested the same scenario with an `integer` column. Same results as with `text`:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0dd4027516d124580a5f8d8a13f6ae83)*

#### Conclusion

`COALESCE` in combination with `FULL OUTER JOIN` seems to get special treatment from the query planner, so that indexes are applicable. It's used in the expression to compute the output column `identifier`, explicitly in your original or implicitly in my simplified query. And that seems to match how the join condition of a `FULL OUTER JOIN` is implemented internally. This falls flat for some reason when `varchar` is used - most likely because of the added (logically irrelevant) cast to `::text`.

Comment: Do you think that this qualifies as a bug? Should I add to a bug tracker somewhere?